Estoy intentando escribir un test que asegura que no se use una funcion de flecha
Estoy escribiendo un test para mis estudiantes que revisa la implementacion de una funcion de flecha. Mi intencion es que entiendan que la funcion de flecha no siempre ayuda, la solucion es esta:
const profile = {
    name: 'Alejandra',
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};

Pero si ellos escriben esto como solucion:
const profile = {
    name: 'Alejandra',
    getName: () => {
        return this.name;
    }
};

Quiero que el test le de un error.
Pero ahorita lo que tengo no hace eso:
describe('profile', function() {
    it('should return the correct name using a regular function', function() {
        const profile1 = {
            name: 'Alejandra',
            getName: function() {
                return this.name;
            }
        };

        expect(profile1.getName()).toBe('Alejandra');
    });

    it('should not return the correct name using an arrow function', function() {
        const profile2 = {
            name: 'Alejandra',
            getName: () => {
                return this.name;
            }
        };

        expect(profile2.getName()).not.toBe('Alejandra');
        expect(profile2.getName()).toBeUndefined(); // Or whatever `this.name` evaluates to in your environment
    });
});

¿Que me falta?

Dices que Pero ahorita lo que tengo no hace eso, entonces que es lo que hace ??

@Yussef, me aprueba la solucion, no importa si utilizan la clave 'function' o si utilizan una funcion de flecha. Mi deseo es que en un solo bloque de 'it' pase si utiliza la clave 'function' o no lo pase si utilizan la funcion de flecha.

Tal vez te estás complicando, revisa la representación como cadena de la función usando toString.
Para evitar problemas de comparación simplemente elimina los espacios en blanco de esa cadena y ya podrás buscar si contiene "=>"


const profile = {
  name: 'Alejandra',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

const profile1 = {
  name: 'Alejandra',
  getName: () => {
    return this.name;
  }
};

const firstFunction = profile.getName.toString();
const secondFunction = profile1.getName.toString();
console.log(firstFunction);
console.log(secondFunction);

const noSpacesF1 = firstFunction.replace(/\s/, '');
const noSpacesF2 = secondFunction.replace(/\s/, '');

console.log('La primera función es una función flecha: ', (/^([^{=]+|\(.*\)\s*)?=>/).test(noSpacesF1));
console.log('La segunda función es una función flecha: ', (/^([^{=]+|\(.*\)\s*)?=>/).test(noSpacesF2));



La expresión regular la obtuve de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542815/6999690
En jest quedaría así:
expect(profile.getName.toString().replace(/\s/, '')).not.toMatch(/^([^{=]+|\(.*\)\s*)?=>/);

Esto en base a su documentación.

esto funciona aqui como esta escrito pero no funciona en el ambiente que loy estoy usando , me dice: Expected 'functiongetName() {         return this.name;       }' to match /^([^{=]+|\(.*\)\s*)?=>/.

@Daniel Y eso es correcto, porque la función no es una función flecha, recuerda que  la expresión regular da verdadero solamente si es una función flecha. De cualquier manera ya te he actualizado la respuesta para que copies y pegues

Me parece que tu problema está en la logica (es "como" si aplicaras una doble negación). Estas cambiando el test y el resultado esperado al mismo tiempo
Es como si quisieras probar si un número es par y dijeras:

4 es par -> Correcto
5 no es par -> También es correcto (aquí simplemente deberías haber preguntado si era par, para fallar la prueba)

En tu primer test dices que:
expect(profile1.getName()).toBe('Alejandra');


La función profile1.getName() debe retornar Alejandra

Lo que para el caso que has puesto es correcto, esa función retorna Alejandra

En tu segundo test pones lo siguiente
expect(profile2.getName()).not.toBe('Alejandra');


La función profile2.getName() NO debe retornar Alejandra

Lo cual para ese caso es correcto, esa función NO retorna Alejandra, así como tambien estas diciendo que:
expect(profile2.getName()).toBeUndefined();


La función profile2.getName() debe retornar undefined

Que si en el scope no existe una variable Name, será también correcto.
Y por esto te aprueban todos tu test.
La solución: Quitar la función not
expect(profile2.getName()).toBe('Alejandra');

